# SQL from a basic to date query to scheduled date entry query

Tags: sql, sql-server

We manually run scripts to pull the total time our staff had inputted on a certain date and we use the greater than and less than to select a date range. Can anyone provide me information on how to make it so for scheduling scripts?

Can we get help on how we set the date to be "entry that was entered 2 weeks upon when this script runs"

```
select SMEMBER.SLNAME, sum(TTIME.TTIME) as TotalTime
from TTIME
inner join SMEMBER on SMEMBER.SNUM = TTIME.SNUM
where TIDATE >= '2/15/2021' and TIDATE <= '2/19/2021'
group by SMEMBER.SLNAME;
```

Comment: Please tag with database platform.  Not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
select SMEMBER.SLNAME, SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00:00', TTIME.TTIME)) as TotalTime
from TTIME
inner join SMEMBER on SMEMBER.SNUM = TTIME.SNUM
where TIDATE >= '2/15/2021' and TIDATE <= '2/19/2021'
group by SMEMBER.SLNAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select m.SLNAME, sum(t.TTIME) as TotalTime
from TTIME t inner join
     SMEMBER m
     on m.SNUM = t.SNUM
where TIDATE >= dateadd(day, -14, convert(date, getdate())
group by m.SLNAME;
```

This assumes there are no future dates.  If there are, then add:

```
where TIDATE < convert(date, getdate())
```

Of course, this doesn't include the current date.  Just adjust the inequalities if you want to include them.